# Form inside a php while loop not posting data

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a cart system for a webshop. The form is supposed to post infomation to `addtocart.php` but it is not posting the data and i have no idea why.

The form with the problem:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM parts ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6"; 
$result = mysqli_query ($connect, $query);                                                  

while( $record=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {

$partnr=$record['partnr'];                                  
$specs=$record['specs'];
$price=$record['price'];

echo    '<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">';
echo    '<div class="thumbnail">';
echo    '<img src="afb/'.$partnr.'.png" alt="">';
echo    '<div class="caption">';
echo    '<h4 class="pull-right">€'.$price.'</h4>';
echo    "<h4><a href='item.php?id=".$partnr."'>".$partnr."</a>";
echo    '</h4>';
echo    '<p> '.$specs.'';

echo    "<form class='form-signin' action='addtocart.php' method='POST' autocomplete='off'>";
echo    "<input type='hidden' name=".$partnr." value=".$partnr.">";
echo    "<input type='hidden' name=".$specs." value=".$specs.">";
echo    "<input type='hidden' name=".$price." value=".$price.">";                       
echo    "<input type='submit' value='Add to cart' class='btn btn-default'>";    

echo    "</form>";  
echo    '</div>';
echo    '</div>';
echo    '</div>';                       
}                                           
?>
```

Contents of addtocart.php

```
<?php

session_start();    
require_once('includes/connect.php');

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$partnr = $_POST['partnr'];
$specs = $_POST['specs'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

echo $id;
echo $partnr;
echo $specs;
echo $price;
echo $_POST['partnr'];
echo $_POST['specs'];
echo $_POST['price'];

$query = "INSERT INTO cart (customer_id, partnr, specs, price, quantity) VALUES ('$id', '$partnr', '$specs', '$price', 1)";
mysqli_query ($connect, $query) or die ("Insert Failed"); 

echo 'window.location = "cart.php";';
?>
```

The result of addtocart.php

1Insert Failed

Comment: This doesn't help you btw `or die ("Insert Failed");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the value of the variables as names in your form.
Change it to the name and you will be able to read them correctly.

```
echo    "<input type='hidden' name='partnr' value='".$partnr."'>";
echo    "<input type='hidden' name='specs' value='".$specs."'>";
echo    "<input type='hidden' name='price' value='".$price."'>";
```

Comment: We don't know that for certain. Maybe it is populating correctly.

Comment: Look at the original code: `name=".$partnr." value=".$partnr.">`. That can't be right.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i worked!

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'd of thought that maybe they meant to use `name='".$partnr."'`

Comment: Then the real issue here is that the OP never bothered to check for errors with error reporting and would have thrown them undefined index notices.

Comment: Or even read the code with some attention..